# Closing a question as off-topic with no alternate direction

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, off-topic

When closing a question as "Off Topic", shouldn't mods maybe add some education, instruction or help directing the OP to the correct place to post the question, instead of just simply closing with an unhelpful link to the FAQ?

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643216/website-payments-pro-hosted-solution-sandbox

I realize this is not always the case, but I am sure that there is a Stack Exchange site where this would have been an appropriate question.

Comment: Counter-question: Shouldn't it be up to the user to read the FAQ and make an educated decision as to whether their question is on-topic or not?

Comment: @mxmissile: dont expect you will receive positive response to this type of questions. you will be shot down by continuous down votes(with no proper explanation).. I am used to this and gave up on asking this type of Q's..

Comment: @javauser, did you by chance happen to read the FAQ for meta? Votes on meta are different.

Comment: Stack Overflow gets over 7,000 new questions every day. They can't be processed all with custom-tailored, helpful messages.

Comment: @Anthony pegram: Since downvotes mean differently on Meta I wish downvotes dont reduce reputation resulting in revoking rights received from reputation. I am really afraid of bringing or asking anything out of the box(chances of it being appreciated are so low)

Comment: @javauser You were not downvoted because of the question you were asking, you were downvoted because you posted the same question multiple times, which is not the appropriate way to draw attention to questions.  That's completely unrelated to how votes work on meta vs other sites.  Any site will downvote you for doing that.

Comment: @servry: Keeping my question aside dont you think if downvote on meta means showing disagreement on the question, reputation should not be reduced.

Comment: @java it doesn't only mean disagreement

Comment: @Bart I see on FAQ it says differently "On Meta Stack Overflow, voting is often used to express agreement or disagreement, not to point out a lack of quality or helpfulness"

Comment: Moderators don't close all questions anyway. The community does most of them.

Comment: @javauser Exactly. **Often**, not always. In fact, by far the majority of my downvotes are because users didn't do their research, were unclear or their questions are not useful.

Answer (score 7):

There may not be another SE site where it's appropriate to ask.  When there is it's pretty common to see it mentioned in comments.

The majority of active users of any given site are not active users of many other sites, and are unlikely to know of what sites this might be applicable on.  Just because someone knows that the content doesn't belong "here" doesn't mean they know where it does belong.

Most questions also aren't closed by moderators, they're just closed by members of the community with enough reputation to vote to close (5 such votes can close a question).

Answer (score 6):

> shouldn't mods maybe add some education, instruction or help directing the OP where the correct place to post questions like this is, instead of just blatantly closing with an unhelpful link to the FAQ?

No. Think of the formula for intervention like this:

> `( Volume of questions on Stack Overflow / Free time to moderate ) * potential to effect change across a large number of people`

If we were to answer every single post we closed, we'd *literally never have time to close posts* (I can hear some cheering in the background).

In this case, the question is demonstrably off-topic, and there's no site on the Stack Exchange network called "Paypal customer support".  If there is a site that this question would be welcome on, I do not have enough expertise in other sites to say, and the off topic message already says what I'd say anyway.

At current writing, this question has already received 21 views, where at present, the question you referenced only had 14 views. That means that I've already reached more people with this answer than I could have by leaving a redundant comment on that question.